# How to use existing C++ code in .NET (C#)

Tags: c#, c++, code-migration

I would like to create a C# project and implement the existing native (C++) code. Does anyone know about any good tutorial about it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use P/Invoke and you can call unmanaged methods.
I'll post you some examples:
[This](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288468.aspx) is a reference to MSDN official documentation.
[This](http://www.pinvoke.net/) is a community mantained website with most of the common Windows unmanaged libraries along with method signatures and examples

Answer (score 3):

If your C++ code is managed (as you say), then I'd suggest that you leave it as C++ *unless* you have a very good reason to -- future C# (etc.) assemblies should be able to just reference it 'as is'.

Comment: Good spot - I missed that and read it as "existing *un*managed (C++) code". Given the context it could well be a typo.

Comment: I've found through experience it's always worth checking the obvious first -- of course, if it was a typo, then lots have given suitable answers

Comment: my mistake... it's native C++

Answer (score 3):

I assume by *implement the existing code* you mean you want to call it from C#, with minimal changes to the C++ code.

I'm a fan and recent purchaser of the book [C++/CLI in Action](http://www.manning.com/sivakumar/) which has a couple of useful sample chapters online.

This [intro on CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/mcpp/quickcppcli.aspx) is a good starting point.

The author of C++/CLI in Action has a number of articles on CodeProject, scroll down to the C++/CLI section on [his index](http://www.codeproject.com/script/Articles/MemberArticles.aspx?amid=20248).

The [Wikipedia article on P/Invoke](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Platform_Invocation_Services) has a number of reasons why you might not want to use that approach, with which I agree:

- loss of typing support by the compiler
- possible data type or alignment issues as you have to map types by hand
- need to pin garbage-collected objects

The best starting point on MSDN is the [summary article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235282.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try managed wrappers for your C++ code.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/default.asp?url=/library/en-us/vcmxspec/html/vcmg_accessingcodefromframeworkobjects.asp

Answer (score 0):

Probably the easiest way to do this is to create a C++/CLI project, which will enable you to mix managed and unmanaged C++. You can then wrap your existing unmanaged C++ classes with a managed .Net wrapper that your C# code can call directly. MSDN magazine has a good introductory [article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163681.aspx) on C++/CLI.

Interop will only really be useful for calling C-style functions. You can't really use it to interact with pure C++ classes.

Answer (score 0):

I learned this by doing it, so I don't have a good tutorial, but there are a couple things you need to be aware of - managed C++ and C++/CLI both integrate with unmanaged code with very few ugly seams.  This is not the case with C#.  In managed C++, it's quite possible to do something like this:

```
dotNetForm->Text = S"My Project"; // regular managed code
::SetWindowText(dotNetForm->Handle, "Your Project"); // mixed managed/unmanaged
```

whereas in C# you would have to P/Invoke into SetWindowText--not that you really would: it's just a simple example, but you need to be aware that the managed C++ compiler is a weird combination of doing a lot of interop for you transparently and doing nothing for you at the same time (ie, it will do no implicit marashalling).